# Split '-2--1' into -2 and -1

Tags: python, python-3.x, split

I have a string which looks like '-2--1' which means from -2 to -1 for my problem. I want to access both of these numbers from the string. str.split("-") won't work in this case. What are my options?

Edit: I can have a string like '2-5' as well, which means from 2 to 5 (In this case I need to extract 2 and 5) or a string like '-2-5' which means -2 to 5(-2 and 5 are the numbers of importance in this case).

Answer (score 2):

If there is always going to be a double dash `--` you could do this.

```
s = '-2--1'
s.replace('--',' -').split(' ') # ['-2', '-1']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to find all numbers.

```
>>> import re 
>>> re.findall(r'-?\d+', '-2--1')
['-2', '-1']
```

This will work for any characters between numbers. e.g.

```
>>> re.findall(r'-?\d+', '-2---$&234---1')
['-2', '234', '-1']
```

But it assumes a `-` before a number will make it negative, of course

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
s = '-1--2'
result = [int(d) for d in re.findall(r'-?\d+', s)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split on the hyphen that comes after a digit:

```
def splitrange(s):
    return re.split(r'(?<=\d)-', s)
```

Demo:

```
>>> splitrange('-2--5')
['-2', '-5']
>>> splitrange('-2-5')
['-2', '5']
>>> splitrange('2-5')
['2', '5']
>>> splitrange('2--5')
['2', '-5']
```

Answer (score 0):

split the numbers:

```
split= str.split('-')
```

Function to apply negations:

```
def actual(ns, minus=False):
    if not ns:
        return
    n, *rest = ns
    if n == '':
        yield from actual(rest, not minus)
        return
    yield -int(n) if minus else int(n)
    yield from actual(rest)
```

And now you can actualize:

```
numbers = list(actual(split))
```

It will also handle multiple negations....